Issue with Select Element with Custom Class: When activating the Omniscript it doesnt works!
Hello Salesforces Devs!!!
I'm having quite an issue and I'm screaming for help, don't know what I'm missing.
I have a pretty simple task, to show in a Select element on an Omniscript a picklist of Account names.
So, I set Option Source in Custom and call an Apex Class to make a query and send that picklist.
Here is the code, really simple:

So whats the problem? If the Omniscript is not active, this works perfect! It populates with the Name of all the Account records in the org.
But when I activate it, it doesn't work, the picklist is just blank. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?
Tried to implement omnistudio.VlocityOpenInterface but it didn't work neither.
The Select Properties are as follow:

Option Source: Custom
Source: AccountRequestUtil.retrieveAccountData
Controlling Field Type: None



